# Extending a VIM script that separates a paragraph into sentences

Tags: vim

The following script -- as I understand it -- takes a line of sentences (highlighted in visual mode) ending in a `.` and separates them into distinct lines with spaces in between.

```
vnoremap <C-S-O> :<C-U>s/\.\(\s\+\\|$\)/.\r\r/g<cr>
```

**Question 1:** How can this script be extended to include sentences that end in `!` and `?`?

**Question 2:** How can the trailing two blank lines it produces at the end be removed?

**Question 3:** How can each line have inserted at the very beginning the characters "- [ ] "?

So, for example, what I'm asking for is a vim script that would transform the following text:

> This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.

into the following text:

> - [ ] This is sentence 1.
>
> - [ ] This is sentence 2.
>
> - [ ] This is sentence 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\v`(very magical) you dont need so many `\\`.

q1: something like `s/\v([.!?])..../\1\r\r/g`

q2: something like `s/\v([.!?])\s+/\1\r\r/g`

q3: something like `s/\v([.!?])\s+/\1\r\r-[]/g` (but first `-[]` is missing)

Finally:

```
:vnoremap <C-S-O>   :s/\v([.!?])\s+/\1\r\r-[]/g<CR>`<i-[]<ESC>
```

Where the final:

```
`<i-[]<ESC>
```

`i`nserts "`-[]`" in the beginning of the visual area (`<)